# Angular JS filter parameters

Tags: angularjs

I am having a little difficulty using a custom filter. I have searched and searched but cannot find anything relevant, but it should be a quick fix for someone with a bit of experience.

I am using ng-repeat to populate a list, this is from vm.posts.

The user that is logged in and viewing the posts is vm.user, and has a variable vm.user.postsWatched, which is an array of post ids.

I created a custom filter to check if the post has a 'watched' id and if so display it.

In my filter I am printing the contents of both variables and finding that I am not quite getting what I am trying to send in.

Index.html:

```
  <ul class="media-list">
          {{vm.user.postsWatched}}
          <li ng-repeat="post in vm.posts | watchedFilter:vm.posts:vm.user.postsWatched | limitTo:3" class="media">
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">{{post.title}}</h4>
              <p>{{post.date | date: 'short'}} | {{post.content}}</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

On line two, the correct array of post Ids is displayed, so I know there is no issue there.

vm.posts and vm.user.postWatched are passed to watchedFilter as parameters, is there an issue so far??

watchedPost.filter.js:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .filter('watchedFilter', function () {  
           return function(inputs,ids) {
              console.log("ids:" + JSON.stringify(ids[0]) + JSON.stringify(ids[1]) + JSON.stringify(ids[2]));
              console.log("Input:" + JSON.stringify(inputs[0]) + JSON.stringify(inputs[1]) + JSON.stringify(inputs[2]));
             ...

           };
        });})();
```

Before I even begin filtering, the contents of the function parameter 'ids' does not equal vm.user.postsWatched, but rather contains the same info as 'inputs'. So I can tell it's getting a parameter alright, but seemingly not both, if someone could clarify it would really help me out.

If more is needed just ask, many thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML remove the first argument.

```
<li ng-repeat="post in vm.posts | watchedFilter:vm.user.postsWatched | limitTo:3" class="media">
```

When the AngularJS framework calls the filter function, it sets the first argument to the data being piped. The subsequent arguments are set from the arguments in the HTML.

Comment: ok that's brilliant I'll try it out right away, many thanks :D

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg - this is perfect, it was pretty silly to assume I needed to pass a filter the objects I was already iterating, many thanks for your quick response